# Show that composition function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Let $f$ is cont. $g$ is measurable function.Show that composition function $fog$ is measurable

I find an answer for this question:

{$ x:f(g(x))> $ $\alpha $}={$x: g(x)>f^{-1}(\alpha,\inf)$}

But $f^{-1}(\alpha,\inf)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ where $I_n$ are open intervals.

so {$ x:f(g(x))> \alpha $}=$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty g^{-1}(I_n)$ a measurable set.

But I don't understand

$f^{-1}(\alpha,\inf)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$
why this equality hold?

Comment: f is cont. , therefore f inverse will map open set to open set and open set in R can be written as union of open intervals.

Comment: @AnuragJain Yess you are right. Shame on me :(

Comment: It happens, sometimes things which are really easy don't strike us.

Answer (score 1):

As written, it doesn't make much sense. In particular, saying $$g(x)>f^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$$ is nonsensical. Instead, I suspect it is supposed to be written as $$g(x)\in f^{-1}(\alpha,\infty),$$ though even that is an abuse of notation.

The kicker is that $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)>\alpha$ if and only if $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\in(\alpha,\infty).$ I will define and denote the preimage of the set $(\alpha,\infty)$ with respect to $f$ by $$f^{-1}\bigl[(\alpha,\infty)\bigr]:=\bigl\{t\in\Bbb R:f(t)\in(\alpha,\infty)\bigr\}.$$ Thus, $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)>\alpha$ if and only if $g(x)\in f^{-1}\bigl[(\alpha,\infty)\bigr].$

Since $(\alpha,\infty)$ is open and $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}\bigl[(\alpha,\infty)\bigr]$ is open, and so is a union of a countable collection of open intervals $I_n$.

Comment: The question and answer from the book Measure Theory and Integration by G. de Barra..
we may show $f(g(x)<\alpha$ also

@Cameron Buie